# Set margin-left and margin-top as center point

Tags: html, css

I want a div to be centered at a certain point instead of the top left of the div being set at a point.

```
//css code
#div {
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 300px;
}
```

If need be, I'm also using javascript and jquery.

Comment: an example would help more, to see the position you want it to be placed and get the most appropriate answer.

Comment: I see that Switz could want something besides repositioning an element based on the top, left, but this seems like it works in most cases, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have:

`<div>

    <div id="div"></div>

</div>`

Then this will put the center where the top left corner is.

`$('div#div').offset({
    top: $('div#div').offset().top-$('div#div').width()/2, 
    left: $('div#div').offset().left-$('div#div').height()/2
});`

Comment: That doesn't really work perfectly.  I'm attempting to modify it, but thanks.